# Конвертатор чисел из арабских в Римские, проблема с девятками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал прогу, которая, в зависимости от разряда и первого числа этого разряда, записывает в ответ тот или иной вариант записи числа. Так вот, все работает как надо, кроме девяток и чисел после 4 тысяч. Было бы неплохо это исправить, т.к. сам проблему не нашел. Надеюсь на максимально простой вариант и желательно - объяснение. Код ниже.

```
inp_='3948'


roman_num={1:'I', 5:'V', 10:'X', 50:'L', 100:'C', 500:'D', 1000:'M'}
    #answ_dict={}
answer=''  # Var for exit
multiplier=1   # Var for optimize code
counter=0   # NVRMND


    
    
for i in range(len(inp_)-1):   # Setting the multiplier 
    multiplier=multiplier*10
#print(multiplier)


while len(inp_)!=0:   # While we have at least one digit
    
    num=int(inp_[0])  # Var for make code simoly for read
    if 0<=(num-5)<9:  # If number can be presented as summ of 5 and other digits before 9
        
        #multiplier=multiplier/10
        answer+=roman_num[5*multiplier]+roman_num[multiplier]*(num-5)   # Adding to output number from multiplier's class multiple 5 and adding numbers from that class multiple 1
        print(f'5, {answer}, {multiplier}')
        #multiplier=multiplier*10
        
    elif num==9:    # If digit is 9, we can present it as N⁞5+N(by multiplier)
        answer+=roman_num[multiplier]+roman_num[multiplier*10]   # Adding to output number from multiplier's class  and adding number from next one class
        print(f'9, {answer}, {multiplier}')
        
    elif num==4:   # If digit is 4, we can pesent it as:
        if len(inp_)>=4:  # If digit from thousands
            answer+=roman_num[multiplier]*num   # Number from multiplier's class printed num times
        else:
            answer+=roman_num[multiplier]+roman_num[multiplier*5]   # N⁞5+N(by multiplier)
        print(f'4, {answer}, {multiplier}')
        #multiplier=multiplier*10
        
    else:   # If num - digit 1-3, we can just write it num times
        answer+=roman_num[multiplier]*num   # Adding number from multiplier's class to output by adding number num times
        print(f'else, {answer}, {multiplier}')
    multiplier=multiplier/10   # Decrease class of multiplier
    inp_=inp_[1:]   # Delete previous class
    print(num-5)

print(answer)
```

Comment: Знаю, что есть много вариантов решения, но я хотел бы именно по своему примеру сделать прогу. Мне хотя бы надо понять, почему не работает двойное неравенство в ( if 0<=num-5<9: ). Дайте пожалуйста ответ на этот вопрос, дальше уже что-нибудь придумаю)

Comment: У вас алгоритм неверный именно для 9,  отсюда и берутся VIIII вместо IX и т.п.

Comment: Можете пояснить, что именно не так? Я понимаю, что накосячил

Comment: Проблема в том, что 9 попадает в вашу проверку, т.к. 9-5 =4, а 0<=4<9, все отрабатывает этот блок  if. Вам надо поменять порядок проверки (в остальном все верно).

Comment: Сначала проверяйте на совпадения с 9 или 4, а потом уже остальные проверки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда уж можно во все стороны гонять числа (оригинал принадлежит [agalen](https://python.su/forum/topic/11173/?page=1#post-70657)):

```
CONV_TABLE = ((1000, 'M'), (900, 'CM'), (500, 'D'), (400, 'CD'),
    (100, 'C'), (90, 'XC'), (50, 'L'), (40, 'XL'),
    (10, 'X'), (9, 'IX'), (5, 'V'), (4, 'IV'), (1, 'I'))

def arab_to_roman( number ):
   if number <= 0: return ''

   ret = ''
   for arab, roman in CONV_TABLE:
       while number >= arab:
           ret += roman
           number -= arab

   return ret

def roman_to_arab( txt ):
    txt = txt.upper()
    ret = 0
    for arab, roman in CONV_TABLE:
        while txt.startswith( roman ):
            ret += arab
            txt = txt[ len( roman ): ]
    return ret


for i in ( 0, 4, 8, 9, 31, 46, 99, 583, 888, 1668, 1989, 2009, 2010, 2011, 3999 ):
    arab = arab_to_roman( i )
    roman = roman_to_arab( arab )
    print (i, arab, roman)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def Arabic2Roman(number):
    # арабские цифры
    arab = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000];

    # римские цифры
    roman = ['I', 'IV', 'V', 'IX', 'X', 'XL', 'L', 'XC', 'C', 'CD', 'D', 'CM', 'M'];

    # если число нулевое - выдать пустой результат
    if number == 0:
        return '';

    result = ""

    pos = len(arab) - 1;

    while number > 0:
        if number >= arab[pos]:
            result += roman[pos]
            number -= arab[pos]
        else:
            pos -= 1

    # вернуть результат
    return result

print(Arabic2Roman(1999))
```

по идее можно, если есть такие числа, ввести 10000, 1000000 и т.д., алгоритм не изменится